# Ubuntu 19.04 no sound on iMac 2019

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, mac

I have a fresh install of 19.04 on a 2019 iMac. There is no sound.

When I run pavucontrol I see the following:

1. In Playback the audio streams are tracked (youtube, music on VLC, movie on Videos)
2. In Output Devices it shows "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo". Under it, in Port there are two options, Speakers or Headphones. Neither produce any sound
3. In Configuration there are two devices listed. One is Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X], with Off selected in Profile, the other is Built-in Audio, with Analog Stereo Duplex selected in Profile.

Alsamixer lists 3 options for Sound cards, - default, 0 HDA Intel PCH, 1 HDA ATI HDMI. When 0 HDA Intel PCH is selected, it only shows one column, called PCM. Nothing is grayed out or muted.

Any help to get sound working is appreciated. Let me know if I should provide further information.

Thanks.

Edit: The output of lspci -knn| grep Audio -A3

`00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [8086:a348] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X] [1002:aae0]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X] [1002:aae0]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961 [144d:a804]`

Comment: Most likely the device isn't supported yet. Please post output of `lspci knn| grep Audio -A3` to your question.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question adding the output of lspci

Comment: The correct device is the Cannon Lake. the other is for HDMI. Maybe it is not properly supported. You can try UKUU kernels. Or maybe some config is needed.

Comment: I updated to the latest stable linux kernel (v. 5.2.10-050210 ) but that didn't make a difference. I am not sure what configs might work. Thanks.